# React JS - Problem with local storage, .map() and textarea value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a web app with reactjs to make the supermarket list.
Each product comes from the project database that is in firestore (google tool) and they are all shown by means of a .map() with their specific image and name.

The idea is to each product the user can add a description or data that they want to remember for their future purchase, this description is entered by the user from a modal component that has a  where the user can write any description about the product. The Modal component is inside the productItemCard component.

In part the localStorage is working fine since this description is not deleted when updating the browser, but the problem is that the description that the user entered for a product is added to all other products. Both those who are on the list and those who are not. The idea is that each product has its own description, that the user can check what he wrote about each one, and that if he does not add a description, the empty textarea will simply appear with its respective placeholder.
https://github.com/franciscominen/supermarket-list-app

```
// MODAL WITH TEXTAREA COMPONENT
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import "./styles.scss"
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';
import { toast, Slide } from 'react-toastify';
import {listContext} from '../../utils/ListContext';


const ModalComponent = ({item}) => {

  // ADD ITEM AND CONTEXT
    const {addItem, note, noteChange} = useContext(listContext);
    
    const onAdd = () => {
      addItem(item)
    }

  // TOAST NOTIFY ITEM ADD
    const notify = () => toast( `Se agregó ${item.name} a su lista.`, {
      position: "bottom-center",
      autoClose: 1500,
      hideProgressBar: true,
      closeOnClick: false,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined,
      transition: Slide
    });

  return (
    
    <Popup
      trigger={<button className="button"> <FiEdit style={{color:'#242424', fontSize:'20px'}}/> 
               </button>}
      modal
      nested
    >
      
      {close => (
      
        <Animated animationIn="fadeIn" animationOut="zoomOut"  animationInDuration={300} 
         animationOutDuration={300}>
          <div className="modal">
            
            <div className="header"> 

              <div className='item'>
                <img src={item.img} alt=""/>
                <h2>{item.name} </h2>
              </div>

              <button className="close" onClick={close}>
                <IoCloseOutline />
              </button>

            </div>

            <div className="content">

            // TEXT AREA
              <textarea
                placeholder={window.location.href === "http://localhost:3000/productos"
                              ? "Agregue aqui una descripcion sobre este producto"
                              : note }
                value={note}
                onChange={noteChange}
              />        
                
            </div>

            <div className='modal_footer' onClick={notify}>
              { window.location.href === "http://localhost:3000/productos" // MODIFICAR AL HOSTEAR
                ? <button onClick={onAdd}>Agregar a mi lista <BsListCheck/> </button>
                : <button disabled style={{display:'none'}}>Agregar a mi lista <BsListCheck/> </button>
              }
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </Animated>
      )}
      
    </Popup>
  );
}

export default ModalComponent;
```

//

```
// MAP PRODUCTS COMPONENT

import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {ProductCard} from '../ProductCardComponent/ProductCard';
import {listContext} from "../../utils/ListContext";

export const ProductList = ({ items }) => {

    const {searchTerm} = useContext(listContext)
    
    return (
        <>
            { items.filter( item => { // SEARCH 
                if (searchTerm == "") {
                    return item
                } else if (item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                    return item
                }
            }).map( item => ( 
                
                <ProductCard 
                    key={item.id} 
                    item={item} 
                />

            ))}
        </>
    )
};
```

//

//

```
PRODCUT CARD COMPONENT
    import React, {useContext} from 'react';
    import "./styles.scss"
    import {RiAddFill} from "react-icons/ri";
    import {listContext} from "../../utils/ListContext";
    import { toast, Slide } from 'react-toastify';
    import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
    import {Animated} from "react-animated-css";
    import ModalComponent from './DescripcionModal';

export const ProductCard = ({ item }) => {

    const {addItem} = useContext(listContext)

    const notify = () => toast( `Se agregó ${item.name} a su lista.`, {
        position: "bottom-center",
        autoClose: 1500,
        hideProgressBar: true,
        closeOnClick: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        transition: Slide
        });

    const onAdd = () => {
        addItem(item)
    }

    return (

        <>
            <Animated animationIn="zoomIn" animationOut="fadeOut" isVisible={true} animationInDuration={500} animationInDuration={500} >
                <div className='card_product' >

                    <div className='btns_container'>

                        <ModalComponent item={item} />
                        
                        <button onClick={onAdd}>
                            <RiAddFill onClick={notify}/>
                        </button>

                    </div>

                    <img src={item.img} onerror="this.src='https://ctkbiotech.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/not-available.jpg'"/>

                    <h1>{item.name}</h1>

                </div>
            </Animated>
        </>
    )  
};
```

// ITEMS IN USER LIST COMPONENT

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import './styles.scss';
import {listContext} from "../../utils/ListContext";
import {IoCloseOutline} from "react-icons/io5";
import ModalComponent from "../ProductCardComponent/DescripcionModal"

const ItemsInList = () => {

    const { list, removeItem, note } = useContext(listContext);

    return (
        <>
        <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'column', margin:'20px 0'}}> 

                {list.map(({item}) => {

                    return (
                        <>
                            <section className='listProducts_container'>

                                <div className='list_product' id='listProduct'>

                                    <div className='item_detail'>
                                        <img src={item.img} />
                                        <div className='descipt_container'> 
                                            <h2>{item.name}</h2> 
                                            <p style={{color:'grey', fontSize:'14px'}}>
                                                {note}
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
                                        
                                        <ModalComponent item={item}/>
                                    
                                        <button onClick={()=>{removeItem(item)}}>
                                            <IoCloseOutline style={{marginLeft:'10px'}}/>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    

                                </div>

                            </section>
                        </>
                    )
                })}
        </div>
    </>
    )
}

export default ItemsInList;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here

```
<p style={{color:'grey', fontSize:'14px'}}>
  {note}
</p>
```

This *note* is a singular variable, not one tied to a specific item. I think what you are looking to do is store the *note* in the item so, you want to update the item's note and display that same note:

```
<p style={{color:'grey', fontSize:'14px'}}>
  {item.note}
</p>
```